# Maximum value for area problem

Tags: calculus

> From the area bounded by $f(x) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$ and lines $x=t$, $x= t + \frac12$, for which value of $0 \leqslant t \leqslant \frac32$ is the area the largest possible?

We we're asked to use integration for this so we would probably need to determine $\int\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x)dx$ first. This resulted in $-\frac{2\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)}{\pi}+ C$, but how should I continue from here? The idea of using the parameter $t$ confuses me.

Comment: Integrating is not necessary, this is a second fundamental theorem of calculus problem

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The question is asking you to maximize the function

$$A(t) = \int_t^{t+\frac{1}{2}} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} x\right)\:dx$$

for $t\in \left[0,\frac{3}{2}\right]$

Comment: Could you elaborate on how did you come up with the limits for the integral?

Comment: @Viktor The question tells you this directly. There isn't much to elaborate on.

Comment: I got the following from this $f'(t) = \sin(\frac{\pi t}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}) - \sin(\frac{\pi t}{2})$, but finding the roots of this is not very easy to do?

Comment: @Viktor It's easy if you look at it geometrically. $\sin$ increases from $0$ to $\pi/2$ then starts decreasing. One of the $\sin$ is ahead of the other one, and because of the symmetry, they will equal the same thing when the leading one is equally ahead of the peak as the trailing one is behind the peak. Since they are $\pi/4$ apart, their arguments should be located at $5\pi/8$ and $3\pi / 8$, respectively. Which implies $t = \frac{3}{4}$

Comment: @Viktor another way to look at it, since $\sin(\pi - x) = \sin x$, simply solve the equation $\pi - \frac{\pi t}{2} = \frac{\pi t}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4} \implies t = \frac{3}{4}$